# Java Logging: log everything >debug but only when an error occured

Tags: java, logging

During a request processing there are bunch of debug logs logged. At some point there might an error be logged if problem occurs. Idea: when no error hapens during whole request processing I would like to ignore all debugs, BUT if error happens, I would like to see in logs all preceeding and succeding debugs.

Is there any out-of-the-box solution for that (in log4j, logback or any other), or must I implement some kind of wrapper for my Logger, that will "cache" debugs per Thread until they are needed?

Comment: My question got "-1" without any comment... Be a man!

Comment: As Ralph indicated, there is a plan to add a function like this to log4j 2.

Answer (score 5):

It is not a built in solution but here it mys draft implementation what could is quite minimal and easy to integrate. It isusing log4j2 and there is no need to change your client code if you are already using log4j2 or slf4j.

So the corresponding test case

```
  @Test
  public void no_error_so_no_log() throws Exception {
    LogEventCollector.clean();
    try {
      log.debug("hello world");
      log.debug("some debug again");
    } finally {
      LogEventCollector.clean();
    }
  }

  @Test
  public void error_so_log_from_the_beginning() throws Exception {
    LogEventCollector.clean();
    try {
      log.debug("hello world");
      log.error("some error", new RuntimeException("whatever"));
      log.debug("some debug again");
    } finally {
      LogEventCollector.clean();
    }
  }
```

`LogEventCollector` will take care of initialize and the cleanup on you web app request thread. It could be put into a servlet `Filter`.

I have created my custom Appender. The core of the appender is the following:

```
    @Override
    public void append(LogEvent event) {
      if (Level.ERROR.isLessSpecificThan(event.getLevel()))
        LogEventCollector.markError();
      if (!LogEventCollector.hadError()) {
        LogEventCollector.collect(event);
        return;
      }
      for (LogEvent collected : LogEventCollector.events())
        push_log_out(collected);
      //and the current one
      push_log_out(event);
    }
```

Method `push_log_event` is the real logging. It could your custom implementation or a delegate to an other one (like AsyncAppender).

the `LogEventCollector` itself:

```
  public class LogEventCollector {
    static ThreadLocal<Context> LOG_COLLECTOR = new ThreadLocal<Context>() {
      @Override
      protected Context initialValue() {
        return new Context();
      }
    };

    public static void clean() {
      LOG_COLLECTOR.get().clean();
    }

    static class Context {
      boolean had_error = false;
      List<LogEvent> events = new ArrayList<LogEvent>();

      public void clean() {
        had_error = false;
        events = new ArrayList<LogEvent>();
      }
    }

    public static void markError() {
      LOG_COLLECTOR.get().had_error = true;
    }

    public static boolean hadError() {
      return LOG_COLLECTOR.get().had_error;
    }

    public static void collect(LogEvent event) {
      LOG_COLLECTOR.get().events.add(event);
    }

    public static List<LogEvent> events() {
      List<LogEvent> ret = LOG_COLLECTOR.get().events;
      LOG_COLLECTOR.get().events = new ArrayList<LogEvent>();
      return ret;
    }

  }
```

I think it must be enough to customize for your own needs.

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you are asking for is captured in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1137.

Comment: that issue looks exactly like the circumstance we're dealing with. Only errors are logged to prod to reduce overhead, but we need debug logs too just for the request that threw an error to help diagnose. Do you know if log4j2 has a solution for this yet over the past few years? Or is that issue the root source to encompass the implementation work needed?

Answer (score 2):

You are talking about [ringbuffer logging](http://www.exampler.com/writing/ring-buffer.pdf), also known as [backtrace logging](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/releases/tag/v1.4.0).

You can implement this in Java using [terse-logback's ringbuffer feature](https://tersesystems.github.io/terse-logback/guide/ringbuffer/#dumping-ring-buffers).

```
<ringBuffer name="JDBC_RINGBUFFER">
    <capacity>${jdbc.ringBuffer.capacity}</capacity>
</ringBuffer>
```

and then dumping the ring buffer happens by logging to a control appender:

```
<logger name="JDBC_RINGBUFFER_LOGGER" level="TRACE" additivity="false">
    <!-- This appender dumps contents of the ring buffer when an event is received. -->
    <appender class="com.tersesystems.logback.ringbuffer.DumpRingBufferAppender">
        <!-- Event source -->
        <ringBuffer-ref ref="JDBC_RINGBUFFER"/>

        <!-- Event source -->
        <appender-ref ref="ASYNC_JDBC"/>
    </appender>
</logger>
```

Ringbuffer logging can be very useful, but does have some drawbacks from only being in memory and only a list.  There's another appender to SQLite, [Blacklite](https://github.com/tersesystems/blacklite/), that lets you keep the SQLite instance only in memory, and that way you can more easily query it.

Comment: I wish it were that simple. If multiple errors occur in a row you have a problem. The first error will start writing the ring buffer but you cannot block other logging while this is happening, so you will need another ring buffer. That may also get triggered while the first is still wring which could cause the events from the ring buffers to be interleaved - ie log events would appear out of order in the file being logged to. If it were as simple as you say LOG4J2-1137 would have been resolved years ago.

Comment: I've found two ways around the ordering problem.  The first is to write "dumped" events into a specific dump appender, rather than writing it to the regular logging output to avoid interleaving in a log-structured storage like kafka or file.   The second is to write to a database (as above in the example) and then query by timestamp.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "The first error will start writing the ring buffer" causing blocking here -- can you elaborate?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know of any system that would work that way.  It would need enough memory to buffer an unlimited amount of logs in order to write it out (which would then potentially take a very long time, or even run out of disk space) at a later time.  Every logging system I have encountered determines whether or not to write the log message at the time the log message is logged, not later.

You could, however, include suitable (potentially unique to a request) markers with the debug messages and then search or filter the log file after the fact to find the debug messages associated with the error.  Or you would need to build your own data structure to contain the data that would, potentially, be written later and write it when you encounter an error and discard it when you reach some boundary at which you, as the application writer, know it will never be needed.

Comment: Well basically I agree to all you write. But my approach makes sense in some scenarios: when we are talking about webservices, that are handling small pieces of work (thus small number of debug logs). In such case there would be no big memory nor IO overhead, and in return we can get debug logs even on production environments, where often no debugs are available in logs (thus harder to analyse the bugs)

Comment: As the application developer you'll need to make the queue of log messages and deliver it to the logging library when applicable and clear it when applicable.  I would write my own 'Logger' class that wraps the Logger from slf4j and implements the queue along with a method to clear the queue.